# How to get console logs using ASL in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, nslog

I would like to get console logs using ASL. I have written following code and i got all console logs in iPhone Simulator but when i use iPhone 4.1 and iPad, i got less console not fully means from starting onwards. I have tried a lot.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getAppLogByApp:(NSString *)appName
{
    NSMutableArray      *lObjAppLogsPtr = (NSMutableArray *)nil;
    LogInfo         *lObjLogInfoPtr = (LogInfo *)nil;

    aslmsg q, m;
    int i;
    const char *key, *val, *lAppName;
    NSDateFormatter *lObjDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [lObjDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


    q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);

    //also set the log level to fetch if is set to the global variable m_cObjLogMessageLevel
    const char* lObjASLLogLevel = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", m_cLogMessageLevel] UTF8String];
    asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, lObjASLLogLevel, ASL_QUERY_OP_LESS_EQUAL | ASL_QUERY_OP_NUMERIC);
    //asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, lObjASLLogLevel, ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL | ASL_QUERY_OP_NUMERIC);
    //if appName passed to it then fetch the logs for this application only
    if ((NSString *)nil != appName && 0 < appName.length)
    {
        lAppName = [appName UTF8String];
        asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_SENDER, lAppName, ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);
    }

    aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);

    while (NULL != (m = aslresponse_next(r)))
    {
        if ((NSMutableArray *)nil == lObjAppLogsPtr)
        {
            lObjAppLogsPtr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(m, i))); i++)
        {
            NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];

            val = asl_get(m, key);

            NSString *lObjValString = nil;
            if (nil != val)
            {
                lObjValString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
            }
            else
            {
                //NSLog(@"Val in nil");
                lObjValString = @"";
            }

            if ((LogInfo *)nil == lObjLogInfoPtr)
            {
                lObjLogInfoPtr = [[LogInfo alloc] init];
            }


            if(YES == [keyString isEqualToString:@"Level"])
            {
                lObjLogInfoPtr.m_cObjLevel = lObjValString;
            }
            else if(YES == [keyString isEqualToString:@"Time"])
            {
                //convert the time to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
                time_t time = strtol(val, NULL, 0);

                NSDate *lObjDatePtr = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time] copy];
                NSString *lObjDateStringPtr = [lObjDateFormatter stringFromDate:lObjDatePtr];
                lObjLogInfoPtr.m_cObjTime = lObjDateStringPtr;
            }
            else if(YES == [keyString isEqualToString:@"Sender"])
            {
                lObjLogInfoPtr.m_cObjSender = lObjValString;
            }
            else if(YES == [keyString isEqualToString:@"Message"])
            {
                lObjLogInfoPtr.m_cObjMessage = lObjValString;
            }
        }

        //Add the loginfo array
        [lObjAppLogsPtr addObject:lObjLogInfoPtr];
        //Release the loginfo and set it to nil for further use
         [lObjLogInfoPtr release];
        lObjLogInfoPtr = (LogInfo *)nil;
    }

    if (NULL != r)
    {
        aslresponse_free(r);
    }

    //free the als msg object
    asl_free(q);
    [lObjDateFormatter release];


    return lObjAppLogsPtr;
}
```

Here `LogIngo` is a subclass of `NSObject`.
Please help me about it. I have been trying since one week.

Comment: ASL means? Is it framework?

Comment: @guarav: ASL means apple system logs which provide all console logs like error, warnigs..and for more details see this asl.h file.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior on the Mac (and therefore in the iOS Simulator) is different; on the Mac, by default, a process can read log entries made by other processes. On an iOS device, ASL will *only* return log entries made by *your* process, and only if you explicitly set the `ASL_KEY_READ_UID` to "`-1`".

Also, logs are pruned rather aggressively on device, and may only include entries made by the current run of your application. (If you want to persist your log entries beyond that and you're using Swift, you may want to look into a more robust logging package such as [CleanroomLogger](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger).)

If you're using Swift, there's a new open-source project called [CleanroomASL](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL) that provides a type-safe API for reading and writing Apple System Log entries. Using CleanroomASL, searching for ASL log entries looks like:

```
let client = ASLClient()
let query = ASLQueryObject()

client.search(query) { record in
    if let record = record {
        // we've gotten a log entry for the search.
        // 'record' is of type ASLQueryObject.ResultRecord
    }
    else {
        // there are no more log entries to process
    }
    // return true while we still want to get results
    // or return false when we don't want to process more
    return true
}
```

You can constrain your search query by setting additional query keys:

```
query.setQueryKey(.Message, value: nil, operation: .KeyExists, modifiers: .None)
query.setQueryKey(.Time, value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - (60 * 60)), operation: .GreaterThanOrEqualTo, modifiers: .None)
```

The code above would return all ASL log entries recorded in the last 5 minutes that also have a value for the `.Message` attribute.